# I want to Pass the text inside anchor tag when clicked on that tag and to show the same text on the directed page

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

This is my `discover.html` file

```
<form action="POST">
    <div class="swipe-area">
      <div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          {% for topic in topics %}
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <a href="{% url 'content' %}" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">
                <h1 name="headings" data-tooltip="{{ topic.description }}" data-tooltip-location="bottom">
                  {{ topic.heading }}
                </h1>
              </a>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div> -->
    </div>
  </form>
```

I want to pass the value of h1 tag that is `{{ topic.heading }}` when clicked on that link to the page that link takes me.

```
              <a href="{% url 'content' %}" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">
                <h1 name="headings" data-tooltip="{{ topic.description }}" data-tooltip-location="bottom">
                  {{ topic.heading }}
                </h1>
              </a>
```

Below is my `views.py` file

```
def content(request):
    heading = request.GET['headings']
    content = Search.objects.all().filter(title__contains = heading)
    context = {'content': content}
    return render(request, 'search/content.html', context)
```

So I want that variable value in my `content.html` page.
Please tell me how to tackle this problem, I have been stuck here for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the heading in the link href.

```
      <a href="{% url 'content' %}?heading={{topic.heading}}" style="color: white; text-decoration: none;">
        <h1 name="headings" data-tooltip="{{ topic.description }}" data-tooltip-location="bottom">
          {{ topic.heading }}
        </h1>
      </a>
```

This will output something like `<a href="http://localhost:8000/content?heading=foobar"></a>`, then when user clicks on this link, the `heading` parameter will be added in `request.GET`.

You need to modify your view accordingly `heading = request.GET['heading']`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the help but I am getting an error `MultiValueDictKeyError at /content/`

Comment: It's probably because you wrote `heading = request.GET['headings']` so headingS with plural, but I used singular in my code.

Comment: What is the output of `print(request.GET)` ? When do you get this error, when clicking the link ?

Comment: Can't get to the `print(request.GET)`, and yes this error comes when clicking the link.

Comment: This error doesn't get displayed if I use `heading = request.GET.get('headings', False)` but the value of `heading` which I get is "False"

Comment: If you copy pasted my code, you should write `heading=request.GET.get('heading', False) # note the SINGULAR`

Comment: Yo, it worked. Thank you so much :-) But I am wondering how it worked. How by passing `heading` in the `href` attribute can be requested by `request.GET.get(key, default)`

Comment: I've edited my anwser. If I have answered your question, please consider accepting and upvoting this post :)

Comment: I want to let you know that `heading=request.GET.get('heading', False)` is the correct variable instead of `heading = request.GET['heading']` because latter may invoke `MultiValueDictKeyError`. Once again thank you.

Comment: Extra tip about your issue https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/passing-parameters-directly-in-the-query-string-of-a-url.html